# How to correctly check tokens payload with passport-jwt?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt, passport.js

Im currently trying to implement passport-jwt and i have a method that creates my tokens with the user's key in it with jwt-simple.

```
async createToken(u: string, p: string){
    let user = await this.us.model.findOne({'key': u})
    if (user.key == u){
        let payload = {'key': u}
        let token = jwt.encode(payload, "Banana")
        return token;
    }
}
```

I manually put it into postman the token and try to get this route. Im using [pleerock/routing-controllers](https://github.com/pleerock/routing-controllers)
@UseBefore calls middleware before it gets to the method.

```
@Get("/test")
@UseBefore(passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }))
test(@Res() response: Response){
    response.send("Test done.")
}
```

Here is how i set up passport-jwt's strategy

```
let OPTJWT = {
    secretOrKey: 'Banana',
    jwtFromRequest: jwt.ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader()
}
passport.use(new jwt.Strategy(OPTJWT, async ( jwt_payload, done) => {
        console.log(jwt_payload)
        let user = await mongoose.model("users").findOne({'key': jwt_payload.key});
        console.log(user)
        if (user) {
            return done(null, {
                key: jwt_payload.key
            });
        } else {
            console.log("User not found")
            return done(new Error("User not found"), null);
        }
    }
    ));


app.use(passport.initialize())
```

I put in console.log() to print out what the passport gets but console doesnt write anything out. The route only gives back Unauthorized ([Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRCbk.png)) even though im sure the given tokens payload is an existing key in users database.
So my question is what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you initialize passport?

Comment: i updated my sample, yes i do

Comment: Did you test it without any decorations? just simple express.

Comment: the decorations are my routing and removing it then setting up express is not a solution im looking for

Comment: I know that this is not what you are looking for, just for tests, use express (It's easy to setup). This will help you ping point the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was `jwt.ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader()`, for some reason it didnt recognize Authorization header so instead this `jwt.ExtractJwt.fromHeader("authorization")` works.